# Understanding Relation Properties And the Difference Between Associative Entity / Tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have two tables

**Table A** has a primary key, X and attributes A, B, C

**Table B** has a primary key, Y and attributes D, E, F

There also exists a third junction table (let's call this **Table C**): this contains foreign key X,Y

Will the junction table, **Table C**, have access to instance specific attributes of A and B, i.e. will it have access to instance specific attributes A, B, C, D, E, F?

Also, with this junction table, which is also known as a composite entity, what is the difference between a composite entity / junction table, and a normal table with 2 foreign keys inserted into them and nothing else? Why do we make this distinction?

Comment: reallly need help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables don't have access to other tables. Tables aren't machines that interact with each other. Tables are simply variables that hold a set of rows. It is users of a database who access tables via queries.

The common domains in your tables (e.g. **X** in **Table A** and **Table C**) allows you to join them on matching values, i.e. you will be able to access the tables together using a suitable query.

I believe terms such as "junction table" and "composite entity" comes from old hierarchical or network data models. In the Entity-Relationship model, we would call **table C** a relationship relation (as opposed to entity relations like **table A** and **table B**), and in the Relational model, all three tables are simply relations.

**Table C** is more than just two foreign keys. One or both columns should be part of a unique or primary key. If only one column, values of that domain can only appear once in the table, meaning you've got a one-to-many relationship (the uniquely constrained domain is the many-side, since each value can only appear once it can only be associated once with another value). If both columns are part of a unique/primary key, then you've got a many-to-many relationship, in which individual values can appear multiple times but each combination of values can only appear once.

Comment: Thank you that was very clarifying! The term "composite entity" and "relationship relation" are interesting. Would any table that has atleast 2 foreign keys, be called this, or is this term specific to a table that is specifically designed a particular way, that is, having two foreign keys only? 

Thanks again!!

Comment: A relationship relation in ER refers to any association of entity sets. Any table that contains more than one entity key contains a relationship relation. However, it's possible to combine entity relations and relationship relations into the same table, e.g. by denormalizing one-to-many relationship relations into the entity relation of the entity set on the many side.